# Is there a way to trigger a Document Set version capture from JavaScript? Maybe through the REST API?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, 2016, document-set, version-history

According to [this article](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-capture-the-version-history-of-a-document-set/), the only way to create a Document Set version is to do it manually by clicking on "Capture Version".

I know that's not entirely true because [`DocumentSet.VersionCollection.Add()` is available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee561657(v=office.14)) in C#.

I do have event receivers in my solution but I'm not always in that part of the process when I need to capture a version of the Document Set.

Poking around in a browser I found `DocSet.Ribbon.DocSetCommands.createVersion()` when on a Doc Set home page, but that just launches a dialog for the user to enter the version comments.

I suppose I could do some quick DOM manipulation to enter my own comments and "click" the dialog's OK button to submit the form and trigger the version capture, but I also might need to trigger a version capture when I'm not on a Doc Set home page. And even if I was on the home page, having some dialogs flash up and then disappear for no apparent reason is not great UX.

Is there any other way to trigger a Doc Set version capture from JavaScript?

This is specifically for SP 2016.